# Graph a multi index dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi indexed file with values such as these

[image]

How could I plot a dataframe that has separate lines for each symbol in the same graph?

Comment: There are all symbol unique?

Comment: No, it repeats  MSFT, GOOG, AAPL, MSFT, GOOG, APPL, etc

Comment: OK, so use second solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html) for all unique `symbol` values :

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='4.timestamp', columns='1.symbol', values='2.price')
```

If possible duplicated is becessary aggregate by [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='4.timestamp', columns='1.symbol', values='2.price', aggfunc='mean')
```

and then plot by [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
df1.plot()
```